# Consume AngularJS service from simple javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, post, sharepoint

I have a main.js javascript file that has an *init()* function in.

I also have this AngularJS service:

```
(function () {

var app = angular.module('spContact', ['ngRoute']);

app.factory('spAuthService', function ($http, $q) {

    var authenticate = function (userId, password, url) {

        var signInurl = 'https://' + url + '/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0';
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var message = getSAMLRequest(userId, password, signInurl);

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf',
            data: message,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            getBearerToken(data, signInurl).then(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }, function (data) {
                deferred.reject(data)
            })
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        authenticate: authenticate
    };

    function getSAMLRequest(userID, password, url) {
        return 'envelope';
    }

    function getBearerToken(result, url) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var securityToken = $($.parseXML(result)).find("BinarySecurityToken").text();
        if (securityToken.length == 0) {
            deferred.reject();
        }
        else {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: securityToken,
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
                }
            }).success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function () {
                deferred.reject();
            });
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }
});

})();
```

How can I call this services "authenticate" method from the init() function of my main JavaScript file?

This service should return some authentication cookies that I would need for data querying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject this factory to some controller/directive like:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['spAuthService', function (spAuthService) {
    spAuthService.authenticate.then(function (data) { 
        // ...
    });
}]);
```

And this controller `MyCtrl` may be put on some home page and bootstrapped by Angular automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to AngularJS... my main question is, that is it possible to just call this service from the init() function of the javascript file that is loaded when the page is loaded? The module was sent for me like this (using AngularJS), but we don't use this framework anywhere else..

Comment: If you are not using in `Angular` way, just refactor the `factory` to some function. Anyway, it is just returning an object with some utility functions.